# Security flaw relating to special characters in Windows file paths

Tags: c#, windows, special-characters, filenames

I may have found a security flaw in my Windows application. It takes in a string from the user and applies the following logic:

```
string fileName = userInput + ".notSecret";
return new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Is it possible for the user to input any characters that would allow them to enter a new file extension by terminating the file name early?

For example:

> "secret_file.Secret\0"

Comment: In the 50 minutes since you asked this question, you could have set a breakpoint in your code, hit F5 and tried it yourself.  Just saying.

Comment: @Tim- I tried about 20 different special characters including this one and searched extensively on google. When it comes to security, I would rather be safe than sorry, so I asked this SO question in case I missed a possible exploit.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you indicate is most likely not a security flaw.  First, .NET strings are not null-truncated and may contain null characters.  Moreover, if you try to create a file in the `StreamWriter` constructor with a control character, including `\0`, you will find it throws an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
```

Note that there *would* be a security hole if the .NET IO framework supported alternate data streams; a user could write to "`userInput.secret:.notSecret`", coercing a write to an alternate data stream of "userInput.secret".  Since System.IO classes do not support alternate data streams, a `NotSupportedException` is thrown and the rogue file is not written.

There are potential file system implications inherent in using the file extension as a security control.  For instance, if the user has a file with the extension `.notSecret` mapped as a [hard link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097.aspx) to a file with the extension `.secret`, writing to one would also write to the other (since in a hard link, a single file can have multiple paths with different extensions).

Assuming that `userInput` is raw code provided by the user, the code fails to sanitize the user input.  When handling input from untrusted sources, code should assume [all user input is evil until proven otherwise](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/5957.aspx).  If the user's input is expected to be a certain value (e.g., no special characters), code handling the input should ensure it matches, and sanitize it (or throw an exception) if it does not.  Allowing only inputs known to be good is much safer than only disallowing inputs known to be bad.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will definitely sanitize it.